# AHK keymapping and Joysticks

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, remapping, key-binding, joystick

I've been trying to make a AHK script work with my Logitech F310 gamepad. There is 11 buttons on the controller total, however it doesn't recognise the 11th button being an actual button, even Windows can't see it as a button either, the button does however work when I've got Steam open, since if I hold the button down it switches Steam to Big Picture Mode.

By default it's recognised by Windows as a "Generic X-Box Gamepad". I've pretty much got the Xbox 360 controller drivers installed since the controller itself is very much like Xbox 360 controller anyway and works perfectly fine in games. Except for the 11th button not being recognised as an 11th button for AHK, this button would be what would normally be that big X button on a XB360 controller.

I've tried testing with the Joystick script shown from this page here to identify the key mappings for the controller - http://ahkscript.org/docs/scripts/JoystickTest.htm but doesn't recognise the button when pressed.

In my script when I try to do the following for 11th button;

```
Joy11::
```

and

```
WaitForJoy11
```

it tells me

```
Line Text: WaitForJoy11
This line does not contain a recognised action.
```

Why does this not work? and I read on the Wiki it should go up to Joy32.

Comment: Anybody? answers? no?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this appears to be a driver issue with the joystick. Windows does not recognize it as a button, and so AHK doesn't either. There may be ways around this, but without knowing what exactly Windows *does* think the button is, we're in the dark.

The best I could propose is to use one of the many AHK scripts that record and play back the last pressed key (start here https://www.google.ca/search?espv=2&q=autohotkey+last+key&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0CBoQvwUoAGoVChMIiK3R8Mm5yAIVxi6ICh1BfQB2&biw=1440&bih=859).

With one of these scripts, it might be possible to toggle these buttons and have AHK relay what it thinks the key is, after which you can bind it as desired.

Comment: If I can capture raw input from the controller that should at least give some insight to what the command buttons are being read as. I've seen a few scripts floating about somewhere which can read raw input from devices to obtain all their functions.